# Python: nested class with static method fails

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, super

What is *wrong* with the following code?

```
class A:
    def A_M(self): pass
    class B:
        @staticmethod
        def C(): super(B).A_M()
```

error (Python 2.7.3):

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.B.C()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "..x.py", line 36, in C
    def C(): super(B).A_M()
NameError: global name 'B' is not defined
```

**Edit**:
the solution was simple as this:

```
class A:
    def A_M(self): pass
    class B:
        @staticmethod
        def C(): A().A_M()                 #use of A() instead of supper, etc.
```

**Important Note** that there is an issue with this solution. If you change the name of super class (i.e. `A`) then you will have to update all uses inside itself as `A` :)).

Comment: Why do you think you want a nested class? There is almost zero reason to ever have this in Python.

Comment: _" If you change the name of super class (i.e. A) then you will have to update all uses inside itself as A"_ - **That's not what _super class_ means**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        print('bar')

    class B(object):
        @staticmethod
        def bar(obj):
            # A.foo is not staticmethod, you can't use A.foo(),
            # you need an instance.
            # You also can't use super here to get A,
            # because B is not subclass of A.
            obj.foo()
            A.foo(obj)  # the same as obj.foo()

            # A.bar is static, you can use it without an object.
            A.bar()

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        # Again, B.foo shouldn't be a staticmethod, because A.foo isn't.
        super(B, self).foo()

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        # You have to use super(type, type) if you don't have an instance.
        super(B, B).bar()


a, b = A(), B()

a.B.bar(a)
b.foo()
B.bar()
```

See [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278) for details on `super(B, B)`.

Comment: the solution is therefore: `class A:
    def A_M(self): pass
    class B:
        @staticmethod
        def C(): A().A_M()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a fully-qualified name. Also, in python 2.7, you need to use `(object)`, else `super(A.B)` will give `TypeError: must be type, not classobj`

```
class A(object):
    def A_M(self):
        pass

    class B(object):
        @staticmethod
        def C():
            super(A.B).A_M()
```

Finally, `super(A.B)` is essentially `object` here. Did you mean for `B` to inherit from `A`? Or were you simply looking for `A.A_M()`?

Comment: doesn't work: ...error:   `def C(): super(A.B).A_M()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj`

Comment: @Developer: Ok, now read my post again: _"Also, in python 2.7, you need to use (object)"_. `super` only works on new-style classes

Comment: still doesn't work: ...err:     `super(A.B).A_M()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'A_M'`

Comment: @Developer: Keep reading - _"`super(A.B)` is essentially `object` here"_. And `object.A_M()` doesn't exist. _"Did you mean for B to inherit from A? Or were you simply looking for `A.A_M()`?"_

Comment: Even if it was inherited, it still don't think it would work because it's static

Comment: @Eric Simply `A.A_M()`. `B` not to be inherited from `A` but encapsulated within it.

Answer (score 2):

A latecommer, to just encapsulate B in A the easy way is this:

```
class A:
    def A_M(self):
        return "hi"

    class B:
        @staticmethod
        def C():
            return A().A_M()

a = A()
print a.B().C()
```

Not sure this is what you need, but the question was still unsolved, so I guessed.

Comment: `a.B().C()` is not correct. `a.B.C()` is correct (because C is static in B). I voted up your answer, BTW. `gatto`'s answer says the same thing but a little lengthy.