# Python: performance issue implemenating nested classes with staticmethod

Tags: python, class, nested, static-methods

Check the following example working code of our implementation of `nested classes` with mixed `staticmethods`.

```
import time

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        time.sleep(0.1)

    def a1(self):
        print 'a1'

    @staticmethod
    def a2(): 
        print 'a2'

    class B:
        @staticmethod
        def b2():
            A.a2()         #fine.  
            A().a1()       #very bad solution, computation cost is high !!!

        @staticmethod
        def x():
            t = time.clock()
            for i in xrange(100):
                A.B.b2()
            print 'elapsed: %0.1fs'%(time.clock()-t)
```

to use as:

```
A.B.x()
```

The above works but as you may notice for line `A().a1()` in which we have tried to get access to a non-static method `a1` from container class `A` the computation cost is too high. We emphasized this point by having `sleep` in `A` initialization. So you get the point, it can be any time consuming initialization which is necessary in our work, for example. So we don't believe instantiating class `A` in the mentioned line is a good choice. How to not to instantiate `A` in the above but having the job done as exactly as above. The question above has bot been answered anywhere although related ones include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775246/nested-classes-in-python) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210139/python-nested-class-with-static-method-fails).

**EDIT**:
We are not interested in recommendations such as `why use it` etc. The question of our interest as clearly pointed out above is how to improve just this line

```
A().a1()
```

that's all.

Solved in the following way based on advice given by `Martijn Pieters`. We accepted the answer due to showing the way to solve.

```
class B:
    @staticmethod
    def b2(Ai):
        A.a2()         #fine.
        if Ai is None: Ai = A()
        Ai.a1()        #now is fine.

    @staticmethod
    def x():
        t = time.clock()
        Ai = A()
        for i in xrange(100):
            A.B.b2(Ai=Ai)
        print 'elapsed: %0.1fs'%(time.clock()-t)
```

Thank You.

Comment: Sorry, what? You want to execute code requiring an instance of `A` without instanciating `A`?

Comment: I am entirely unclear as to what you are asking, but nested static methods do not behave any different from non-nested static methods. There is no additional performance penalty (other than the attribute lookup, which is not exactly costly) that'd make the situation exceptional.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Note that in the code above we are looking for a solution **not to instantiate `A` million times** just to access to method `a1`. There should somehow to do this only with one instance.

Comment: If `A` takes long to initialize then do it only once, caching the instances. You can do this with a very simple `__new__` method.

Comment: That's just a caching problem; that has **nothing** to do with static methods or nested objects.

Comment: In your question you did **not** state that initialization wasn't important for the `a1` method, or that the `a1` method doesn't have side-effects, so that you can use a single instance of `A`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you run the above example i.e., `A.B.x()` you will see the point. First you may comment line `A().a1()` you will see the response is immediate for 100 repetition. However if you have A().a1() 100 instance of `A` being created which is not necessary for the purpose of the above.

Comment: @Developer: I see what the code does, I am just stating that the problem does not change if it you applied it to regular global functions. You repeatedly call a function that creates an expensive object. Cache the creation of that expensive object and the problem goes away.

Comment: @Developer: In other words, how is your problem different from using three global functions `x()`, `a2()` and `b2()`, with the exact same code but instead referring to the global names?

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK. Do you mean `cache`ing using `__new__` as `Bakuriu` commented or any other advice? Is that the optimum solution?

Comment: @Developer: This is a "Doctor, when I press here it hurts!" question; the only answer I can give you, based on the info here is: "Don't press there then!". How you cache the instantiation of `A()` depends entirely on under what circumstances `A()` can be cached.

Comment: @MartijnPieters See, you almost concluded with no solution! So the question is not trivial. In the above question as we mentioned we want to keep it as it is except for line `A().a1()` which we believe there should be better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with static methods or nested classes. The *exact same problem* exists for global functions:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        time.sleep(0.1)

    def a1(self):
        print 'a1'

def a2(): 
    print 'a2'

def b2():
    a2()  
    A().a1()

def x():
    t = time.clock()
    for i in xrange(100):
        b2()
    print 'elapsed: %0.1fs'%(time.clock()-t)
```

Calling `x()` will still cause expensive instances of `A()` to be created in a loop outside of `b2()`.

You need to devise a caching strategy for creating `A()`. There are too many ways of doing that to sum up here, certainly with so little information on when reusing an instance of `A()` is acceptable over creating a new one.

If you wanted to reuse an instance of `A()` **just** for the loop in `x()` then pass that along as an optional argument:

```
def x():
    t = time.clock()
    instance = A()
    for i in xrange(100):
        b2(instance)
    print 'elapsed: %0.1fs'%(time.clock()-t)

def b2(instance=None):
    a2()
    if instance is None:
        instance = A()
    instance.a1()
```

Now the instance is cached for the duration of function `x()`.

Comment: We are afraid that this is not what we want. We are not interested in changing the structure of our code. The missing point is that with this there is no container structure, you see. where is `A.B.x()`?

Comment: And you already know that the example in the question is to demonstrate our purpose not the original code which may have thousands of methods and structures in it. See the point. No changing the structure is allowed. We are curious to fill our lack of knowledge about the line `A().a1()` mentioned above nothing else.

Comment: I *simplified* the situation to illustrate this has nothing to do with containment. Just add that back in. The structure of nested classes has **nothing** to do with your problem.

Comment: You need to figure out when instances of `A()` can be reused, and then do that; reuse those instances. It doesn't matter **at all** how you are using the instance, the same problem applies to your nested structure as it does to my simplified flattened structure.

Comment: Now we your comments / answer we could solve the problem. Our solution was added at the end of the question. Thanks so much.